# Problems to boot ubuntu partition after updating BIOS from my windows partition

Tags: boot, 14.04, partitioning, windows-8, bios

I have a Toshiba Satellite laptop L50-B-18E.

So, one day the toshiba center asked me to update the BIOS, and I did. But now the menu that asks me what system do I want to start doesn't appear anymore. So I don't know how to boot from my ubuntu partition. The BIOS startup menu doesn't say anything about partitions and the toshiba service tells me that they only deal with windows problems.

Thanks for your help and excuse my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following :

Boot into Ubuntu using the Ubuntu CD and select `Try Ubuntu without installing`

Once Ubuntu starts, open a terminal (`ctrl+alt+t`) and run these commands to install (and run) `boot-repair` :

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`

`sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`

Once the boot-repair window opens, click `Recommended Repair` and follow the on-screen instructions.

Then when you reboot, you should be able to see the menu again (for future reference, it's called the GRUB menu)

Comment: Okay, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Well, just sudo apt-get install boot-repair didn't work (told me it didn't find it), I had to look up how to install the boot-repair application here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and it was only following instructions from that point. Thanks for the help, you're awesome :)

Comment: Any time. I'll update my answer to include the full boot-repair installation instructions.